# Modify object passed in parameter to callback of _each

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

```
var response = _.each(students, function(student){
        return student = _.omit(student, 'userid');
    });
```

Greetings. I am intending to remove some fields from a collection of students I have, that can be represented as:

```
[{"name":"Abena","surname":"Franck LeBoss","sex":"M","dob":"1985", "userid": "123456"},{"name":"Diena","surname":"Stanley","sex":"M","dob":"1996", "userid": "sasd56"}]
```

I am intending to store the result in the variable response, but I still get the same object as students. I've been looking in the documentation, but i could not find any other way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.map` is what you want instead.

```
var response = _.map(students, function(student){
    return student = _.omit(student, 'userid');
});
```

Comment: your answer still yet don't work. The object response at the end is the same as students. No field has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from the `_omit()` itself. I tried with `_pick()` and it works perfectly. Hope someone can explain why it does so.